# Error Recognition in Ansible Ad-hoc Commands

Tags: ansible, ansible-ad-hoc

Is there a way to capture the stdout and stderr separately in bash, maybe as a tuple, for ansible ad-hoc commands? Something like: `stdout, stderr= ansible -i hosts -m shell -a "command"`

Comment: Could you be more specific what is desired output of what command? You can use grep or sed to redirect stdout and stderr to proper log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use option `-t` to log output in JSON format. For example if I execute

```
ansible -m shell -a "echo test" -t tmp localhost
```

then in the file `./tmp/localhost` I'll get this output:

```
{
  "changed": true,
  "cmd": "echo test",
  "delta": "0:00:00.006099",
  "end": "2020-04-14 11:43:01.878959",
  "rc": 0,
  "start": "2020-04-14 11:43:01.872860",
  "stderr": "",
  "stderr_lines": [],
  "stdout": "test",
  "stdout_lines": [
    "test"
  ]
}
```

You can then parse stdout and stderr.